# Is there a way to rewrite dealloc in Automated Reference Counting? Why doesn't it work?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, release, dealloc

I am a second year Computer Programming student who is working on a program in Objective C. (Xcode, if it matters). Right now, we are working on animation and moving animated objects across the screen. Right now, I am dealing with an error that is driving me insane. My program is using ARC, Automated Reference Counting, which supposedly is supposed to help with memory management. However, for some reason, I can't seem to use

```
[super dealloc];
```

It always gives me an error that says "ARC forbids explicit message send of 'dealloc'

Why is this? How do I fix it? It works in my other programs, just not this one?

Also, release doesn't seem to work either. For example, the following code gives me 2 errors:
    [fireBall release];

The error says "'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode" and the next error says "ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'." Why does this happen, how can I fix it? This code works in my other programs. Can someone please explain, or at least provide a link that can solve all my problems? Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3):

You should take some time to fully go through [Apple's Guide on ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

It will save you **tons** of time and it's something definitely worth understanding.

Comment: The short version though, is that without ARC, you are using "Manual Reference Counting" where you explicitly keep track of whether or not you want to keep a particular object around by using commands like `retain`, `release`, and `autorelease` to inform the runtime when it can dispose of an object.  With ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) it automatically determines when you no longer have a reference to an object so that it can dispose of it when you are no longer using it.  Because of this, those commands used in the manual method are no longer used/needed/allowed.

Comment: I commented the lines out, which is basically the same as removing them, right? Well, it gave me an error that says: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) this error looks, quite frankly, terrifying. What is it, how do I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own dealloc method, you just cant call [super dealloc] (ARC calls it automatically). The same is true for release, you dont need to call it as ARC handles placing it in your code

Comment: I commented the lines out, which is basically the same as removing them, right? Well, it gave me an error that says: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) this error looks, quite frankly, terrifying. What is it, how do I solve it?

Comment: can you post some code? its hard to debug without seeing your methods

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just remove that line. ARC takes care of all release/autorelease/dealloc calls.
ARC has 100% (pretty much) insight in the lifetime of your objects and inserts these calls for you.

You can still override the dealloc method to do some cleanup though.

Comment: I commented the lines out, which is basically the same as removing them, right? Well, it gave me an error that says:                     linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)    this error looks, quite frankly, terrifying. What is it, how do I solve it?